# Using # at the beginning of an href hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I know that `#` character within links of hyperlink tag `href` is used to scroll the pointed page to the specified element-id once opened:

`href="//site.com/#some-id"`

when used solely, means to just scroll up to the top of the current page:

`href="#"`

but what about when it is attached to the beginning of a link?

`href="#/phones/phoneid`

will it scroll the pointed page to its top once opened?

Comment: well try it yourself, you'll see that it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` in a `URI` is used to indicate an in-page anchor on a given page.

> I know that # character within links of hyperlink tag href is used to
>   scroll the pointed page to the specified element-id once opened:
>
> ```
> href="//site.com/#some-id"
> ```

It's not so much that it "opens" the page and then "scrolls" to the anchor. It opens the page ***at the anchor*** - the anchor *is part of* the address.

> when used solely, means to just scroll up to the top of the current
>   page:
>
> `href="#"`

Yes. Kind of. But that's because you haven't stated the name of the anchor and the browser can't find it - so the browser doesn't take you to anywhere below the top of the page.

> but what about when it is attached to the beginning of a link?
>
> `href="#/phones/phoneid/"`
>
> will it scroll the pointed page to its top once opened?

Well, there's no need, is there?

```
href="/phones/phoneid/"
```

will *already* take you to the top of the `/phones/phoneid/` page.

In short, a ***hash-fragment*** is part of a web address.

The *hash-fragment* consists of two parts:

1. The hash (`#`)
2. The name of the anchor

Clicking on a `URI` containing a hash-fragment opens the indicated page **at** the indicated anchor.

Clicking on a `URI` which does not contain a hash-fragment opens the indicated page **at** the top.

If a `URI` contains a hash-fragment which has an invalid name (or which isn't named at all), the browser won't be able to find the anchor and will default to opening the indicated page **at** the top.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't. You have to add the `#` to the end of the URL to let it scroll to the top, for example:

```
<a href="/phones/phoneid#">Text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will search for an ID in your DOM. If there isn't an ID like this, nothing happens.
But try it yourself because this is only a speculation.

Answer (score 1):

The url system currently works like this:

`protocol`://`domain.name`/`resource`#`anchor Link`
(syntax simplified for this example)

Adding another resource path after an anchor link makes no sense because the anchor link is assigned to the resource you seek, it cannot be *part* of the resource path.

**Solution:** add the `#` at the end of your link to make it scroll to the top.